# Finding records based on associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, collections

I have 3 models, (Users, Jobs and Reviews). **Reviews** has a ***job_id*** field and **Jobs** has a ***user_id*** field.

```
In my models...
Users:   has_many :jobs
Jobs:    belongs_to :user
         has_many :reviews
Reviews: belongs_to :job
```

How do I write the query to collect all of the reviews for a specific user.id?

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution that i found

```
Review.joins(job: :user).where(users: {id: 1})
```

The query corresponding to the above statement is

```
SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "reviews"."job_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "jobs"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
```